# How can I pass parameters from one function to another

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and trying to figure something out. I have written the code below that should pass the values from one function to another and at the end accept parameters from an object to populate them. However, I can only see the text property of the nameInput object as an output. Please let me know what am I doing wrong?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

function FirstName(props){
    return <h1>Hi, {props.fname.name}</h1>
}

function LastName(props) {
    return (
      <div className="UserInfo">
        <FirstName fname={props.lname} />
        <h2>{props.lname.name}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }

  function FullName(props){
    return (
      <div className="container">
          <LastName lname={props.fulname} />
          <div>{props.text}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }


  const nameInput = {
      name: {
        firstname: 'Savi',
        lastname: 'Dulai',
      },
      text: 'got it to work?'
  };

class ComponentPractise extends Component {
    state = {  }
    render() { 
        return ( 
            <div className="row">
                    <FullName 
                        text={nameInput.text}
                        fulname={nameInput.name}
                    />
            </div>
         );
    }
}

export default ComponentPractise;
```

I would like the output to say "Hi, Savi Dulai got it to work?".
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem like you was lost the context. Function `FullName` is okay, but `LastName` and `FirstName` referenced to wrong props property.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

function FirstName(props){
    return <h1>Hi, {props.fname.firstname}</h1>
}

function LastName(props) {
    return (
    <div className="UserInfo">
        <FirstName fname={props.lname} />
        <h2>{props.lname.lastname}</h2>
    </div>
    );
}

function FullName(props){
    return (
    <div className="container">
        <LastName lname={props.fulname} />
        <div>{props.text}</div>
    </div>
    );
}


const nameInput = {
    name: {
        firstname: 'Savi',
        lastname: 'Dulai',
    },
    text: 'got it to work?'
};

class ComponentPractise extends Component {
    state = {  }
    render() { 
        return ( 
            <div className="row">
                    <FullName 
                        text={nameInput.text}
                        fulname={nameInput.name}
                    />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ComponentPractise;
```

It should works, but I recommend you to change review your function and variable naming to make it more readable.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You're close to the answer, it is just the matter of accessing the props properly. Your fulname prop is an object itself:

```
name: {
  firstname: 'Savi',
  lastname: 'Dulai',
}
```

Access it as `props.fulname.firstname` and `props.fulname.lastname`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<title>myPage</title>
<script src= "https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src= "https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src= "https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

function FirstName(props){
    return <h1>Hi, {props.fname}</h1>
}

function LastName(props) {
    return (
      <div className="UserInfo">
        <h2>{props.lname}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }

  function FullName(props){
    return (
      <div className="container">
          <FirstName fname={props.fulname.firstname} />
          <LastName lname={props.fulname.lastname} />
          <div>{props.text}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }


  const nameInput = {
      name: {
        firstname: 'Savi',
        lastname: 'Dulai',
      },
      text: 'got it to work?'
  };

class ComponentPractise extends React.Component {
    state = {  }
    render() { 
        return ( 
            <div className="row">
                    <FullName 
                        text={nameInput.text}
                        fulname={nameInput.name}
                    />
            </div>
         );
    }
}



ReactDOM.render(<ComponentPractise />, document.getElementById('root'));
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Refactoring/suggestion**

I'd suggest refactoring the code to this, you don't even need the two extra components if you do is this way!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<title>myPage</title>
<script src= "https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src= "https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src= "https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
  function FullName(props){
    return (
      <div className="container">
          <h2>Hi {props.fullname.firstname} {props.fullname.lastname}!</h2>
          <div>{props.text}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }


  const nameInput = {
      name: {
        firstname: 'Savi',
        lastname: 'Dulai',
      },
      text: 'got it to work?'
  };

class ComponentPractise extends React.Component {
    state = {  }
    render() { 
        return ( 
            <div className="row">
                    <FullName 
                        text={nameInput.text}
                        fullname={nameInput.name}
                    />
            </div>
         );
    }
}



ReactDOM.render(<ComponentPractise />, document.getElementById('root'));
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've made this example highly complex, but i guess you're just playing around. So am i:) Best thing to do is stick to one name for stuff you want to pass along. Also, you can console.log(props) above the return within functions to check what is being passed along.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

function FirstName(props) {
  return <h1>Hi, {props.firstname}</h1>;
}

function LastName(props) {
  return (
    <div className="UserInfo">
      <FirstName firstname={props.nameObject.firstname} />
      <h2>{props.text}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

function FullName(props) {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <LastName nameObject={props.nameObject} />
      <div>{props.text}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

const nameInput = {
  name: {
    firstname: "Savi",
    lastname: "Dulai"
  },
  text: "got it to work?"
};

class ComponentPractise extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <FullName text={nameInput.text} nameObject={nameInput.name} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ComponentPractise;
```

Also, you can use IE6 syntax to clean things up a lot, since react parses it back into code all browsers can handle (IE6 JS isn't supported yet). Makes much nicer work. Also got rid of the functional component at the end.

```
import React from "react";

const FirstName = props => {
  return <h1>Hi, {props.firstname}</h1>;
};

const LastName = props => (
  <div className="UserInfo">
    <FirstName firstname={props.nameObject.firstname} />
    <h2>{props.text}</h2>
  </div>
);

const FullName = props => (
  <div className="container">
    <LastName nameObject={props.nameObject} />
    <div>{props.text}</div>
  </div>
);

const nameInput = {
  name: {
    firstname: "Savi",
    lastname: "Dulai"
  },
  text: "got it to work?"
};

export default () => (
  <div className="row">
    <FullName text={nameInput.text} nameObject={nameInput.name} />
  </div>
);
```